# Rails: Select items via checkboxes and then do something with them when button is pressed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, submit

My end goal is to present a list of various active record objects, let users select some of these via checkboxes, and then finally press a button to trigger some action to be taken on them.

As an example, let's say these active record objects represent songs, and I'd like a user to be able to select a list of songs and then click a "Save Playlist" button to pass the list of selected songs to some function in my controller.

I believe that I would first start with a list of songs in my view that have checkboxes next to them.  I think it would look something like this:

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30px;"> Save to Playlist? </th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @songs.each do |song| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box( "songs_selected", "selected_songs[]", { multiple: true }, song.id, nil) %>
        <td><%= song.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I'm understanding the check_box code correctly, what I have should allow me to pass a selected_songs array with the ID's of songs I have selected.

I'm just not positive how to finish this off with a button that's linked to the checkboxes so that when it's pressed it will actually pass that array to a method in my controller.

Any input is appreciated, even if it's pointing out that my design is somehow flawed and there's some better way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of doing this is to set those checkboxes up to become an array. and then wrap it into a `from` so that when button is pressed submit this form and you will get all songs_ids to your controller 
for example: -

```
<%= form_tag you_path, method: :post, id: 'send-songs-id', class: 'form-horizontal' do  %>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:30px;"> Save to Playlist? </th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>    
      <tbody>
        <% @songs.each do |song| %>
          <tr>
              <td><%=check_box_tag 'selected_songs[]', song.id%></td>
              <td><%= song.name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        <%= content_tag :button, :type => :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' do %>
          Submit
        <%end%>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<%end%>
```

this will generate html like this: -

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="selected_songs[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="selected_songs[]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="selected_songs[]" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="selected_songs[]" value="4" />
  // and so on
```

in controller you can get this:

```
def your_action
 song_ids = params[:selected_songs]
 #......
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

The best way to do this would be to put it all within a [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) (assuming pre-Rails-5.1, otherwise [`form_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)).

Effectively, you'd have view markup like this:

```
<%= form_tag playlists_path %>
 <table>
    ...
    <% @songs.each do |song| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box( "songs_selected", "selected_songs[]", { multiple: true }, song.id, nil) %>
        <td><%= song.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create Playlist" %>
<% end %>
```

You'll need the route for the controller method here, I've arbitrarly made up `playlists_path`, assuming you'd have `resources :playlists, only: [:create]` in your `routes.rb` to match your example.